# Forward Declare a Subclass

Tags: c++, header-files, subclassing

I have a Base class A in a header file A.h

```
class A{};
```

in A.cpp I have several subclasses:

```
class B: public A{};
class C: public A{};
```

I would like to instantiate types B and C in a separate file but I can't see how unless I include A.cpp in my other files.  If I forward declare B and C in A.h like this:

```
class B;
class C;
```

Then the instantiating class doesn't know its derived from A.  How would I solve this issue?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: The way I see it, if I put something in a .cpp file, that's stuff that I don't care about any other files being able to see. If I want another file to be able to instantiate B and C, I would put it in the header file along with A (or in separate header files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare `A` in header file for example A.h and include that file into B.cpp and C.cpp, also if you have some non `inline` functions in `A` (functions that defined in `A` declaration are implicitly `inline`) you should create A.cpp, include A.h there as well and define those functions in A.cpp

Comment: How will another class (say D in D.cpp) know that B and C exist and are a subclass of A though if D.cpp just includes A.h and B,C are defined in separate files?

Comment: @EricKulcyk If you need to expose `B` and `C` to other classes in different cpp files you need to have them declared in .h files as well. The rule is simple, if you need to give access to the class from more than one .cpp, declare it in header and include that header wherever you are using that class.

Comment: I guess I was confused about how to do this without declaring B and C twice, once in the header file and once in the .cpp file.  It seems like the solution to this is to put the declaration in B.h and use B::func() in B.cpp, right?

Comment: @EricKulcyk You don't need to declare anything twice, just include header. Yes you are right, put class A{...}; into header and all non inline A::member() into cpp that includes header. You need to declare func() in header thru, but implementation should go into cpp. Or stay in header if it is `inline` function. You may also find useful to read about [ODR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) for better understanding on how all of this works.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file A.h

Create file A.cpp and include A.h         (if required )

Create files B.h and C.h

Include A.h in both of them

Define classes A,B,C in A.h,B.h,C.h **respectively**

Write member functions of classes A,B and C in A.cpp,B.cpp and C.cpp **respectively**

Create a main file and include B.h and C.h

Instantiate objects of B and C in main file